# What is the $\setminus \{a\}$ in $x \in [ a - \delta, a + \delta ]\setminus \{a\}$?

Tags: calculus, notation

What does the  $\setminus \{a\}$ in

$$x \in [ a - \delta, a + \delta ]\setminus \{a\}$$

mean?

Comment: $[a-\delta,a+\delta]\setminus\{a\}$ is same as $N'(a,\delta)$, i.e. the deleted $\delta-$neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: Notice the TeX name you used for \ : "setminus".  perhaps that is a hint of its meaning.

Comment: @GEdgar That was the editor's. but makes sense !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalize from [YoTengoUnLCD's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1690408/308461), this is a notation for set difference. For two sets $A$ and $B$, $A \setminus B = \{e \mid e \in A \wedge e \not \in B\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It just means $x$ is some number greater than (or equal to) $a- \delta$, smaller  than (or equal to) $a+\delta$, but different than $a$.

In general, if $A$ is a set, $A\setminus\{a\}$ is another set which has all the members of $A$ except for $a$.